# Typesetting aligned equation

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I'd like to know whether I am doing the following properly. As in, is this the best way to present the development of the equation?

```tex
\newcommand{\integral}[2]{\int #1 \, \mathrm{d}#2}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \derivative{}{x}\left[uv\right] & = \derivative{u}{x} v & + & u \derivative{v}{x} \\
        \integral{\derivative{}{x}\left[uv\right]}{x} & = \integral{\derivative{u}{x} v}{x} & + & \integral{u \derivative{v}{x}}{x} \\
        uv & = \integral{v}{u} & + & \integral{u}{v} \\
        \integral{v}{u} & = uv & - & \integral{u}{v} \\
        & \text{or} & & \\
        \integral{u}{v} & = uv & - & \integral{v}{u} \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Preview of LaTeX]

What should I do about the second operations' alignment (the plus/minus sign)? Do I need to use ampersand for that line of plus/minus symbols? or only for the equal sign? (see image below)
[image: Preview of LaTeX without second ampersand]

Also what about the 'or' text? How should I deal with that? Should it be under the equal sign or in dead center, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: I’d use either centering or left alignment. The relation and operation symbols are not really strictly related so as to require alignment. To be honest, I’d omit the last line, which is exactly the same as the previous one, mathematically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @egreg, I also thought it shouldn't be necessary, but I'm new to TeX, and wanted to know others opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on providing two alignments points, you should use an `alignat*` environment, not an `align*` environment. But, as @egreg has already remarked in a comment, there's nothing in these equations that requires or at least recommends performing alignment across rows. Hence, using a `gather*` environment may be best.

Both possibilities are illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' and 'alignat*' environments
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % "differential" operator
\newcommand\deriv[2]{\frac{\diff #1}{\diff #2}}
\newcommand{\integral}[2]{\int \! #1 \diff #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\deriv{}{x}\left[uv\right] 
      &= \deriv{u}{x} v &&+ u \deriv{v}{x} \\
\integral{\deriv{}{x}\left[uv\right]}{x} 
      &= \integral{\deriv{u}{x} v}{x} &&+ \integral{u \deriv{v}{x}}{x} \\
uv    &= \integral{v}{u} &&+ \integral{u}{v} \\
\text{hence}\integral{v}{u} 
      &= uv &&- \integral{u}{v} 
\end{alignat*}

\begin{gather*}
\deriv{}{x}[uv] 
      = \deriv{u}{x} v + u \deriv{v}{x} \\
\integral{\deriv{}{x}[uv]}{x} 
      = \integral{\deriv{u}{x} v}{x} + \integral{u \deriv{v}{x}}{x} \\
uv    = \integral{v}{u} + \integral{u}{v} \\
\text{hence}\quad\integral{v}{u} 
      = uv - \integral{u}{v} 
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright then, I guess I'll remove it, I just wanted to know if it was necessary, or if it looked any better, but I guess not, thanks for the alternative also @mico